# Javascript, Stop preventDefault() to pass to child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div container, where for some reason I have to add `e.preventDefault()`, but surprisingly it stops the anchor elements to do their job as well

```js
jQuery('#anything').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="anything">
  <a href="https://google.com"> Link should work </a>
</div>
```

I didn't expect that anchor won't work, I never had to deal with this before. I tried `StopPropagation()` as suggested somewhere, But that didn't work

How can I make the anchor working again?

Comment: can you explaing why are you using preventDefault() ??

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the purpose of this logic? It’s hard for me to understand what’s happening besides the anchor’s event being canceled. Looks like there is something more happening that is not in the code you show. Does the `#anything` element has its own logic on top of cancelling the event?

Comment: @ri-chan your questions are right, using preventDefault() doesn't seem to very sensible on div, I have a div  which includes many forms and those forms shouldn't be submitted until user takes particular action, But the links in that div should work, I think there can be better logics but i was curious about this as well

Comment: Not sure why you are using  e.preventDefault(); if "Link should work". 
However if you are trying to prevent any parent event handlers from being executed e.stopPropagation(); should be it

Comment: Yeah, But `e.stopPropagation()`; should be applied the child element for whom we want to escape `preventDefault()` (in my case anchor), not to the parent element (in my case `div#anything`). it has been explained in answers,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use event delegation and exclude all `a`s from triggering the listener:

```js
jQuery('#anything').on("click", '*:not(a)', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="anything">
  <a href="https://google.com"> Link should work </a>
</div>
```

Or if you want to make sure that no clicks inside children of `#anything` trigger the listener, put `#anything` as the delegation selector instead. In native Javascript this time:

```js
document.querySelector('#anything').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('listener running');
  if (!e.target.matches('#anything')) return;
  console.log('prevented default');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" id="anything">Parent A<span>Child Span</span></a>
```

(though, `preventDefault()` on just a `div` doesn't much sense..?)

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that although your solution stops the `preventDefault()` to get to anchor elements and imply to all other children elements, but `preventDefalut()` actually doesn't imply on the `#anything` div itself. that's why by  your second solution I tried this
`jQuery('#anything').on("click", '#anything, *:not(a)', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();});` But it still doesn't work on the `#anything` div itself. In fact this `jQuery('#anything').on("click", '#anything', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();});` doesn't do anything.
Could you pls help?

Comment: That's why I said `(though, `preventDefault()` on just a `div` doesn't much sense..?)` - it's not clear what you're trying to do with `preventDefault()`, since if it only activates when the target is a `div`, what's the point? Can you explain what the `preventDefault()` is for?

Comment: Actually, your first solution solved my actual issue," I have a div which includes many forms and user shouldn't be able to submit any of them until the user takes the particular action, But the links in that div should work"
But your second solution makes me curious, it doesn't do anything? i mean can we exclude all the child element like this `jQuery('#Parent_element').on("click", '#Parent_element', function(e) {...})`

Comment: If a `div` *had* any default action, then `preventDefault` would prevent that default action from triggering. For example, if you applied the same process to an `a` (default action: redirect), and the `a` has a child `span`, you would be able to see the difference. A click on the `span` would redirect, while a click on the `a` outside would trigger the handler and would not redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your patience,pls last question,take this ex. `<a href="www.google.com" id="a">Click Alert <span>No Alert </span></a>` I just tried this javscript  `jQuery('#a').on("click", '#a', function(e) {
  alert("hello");})` According to you this function should bind only to the Text "Click alert" and not to its child span, but that is not the case, the click event doesn't bind to any element

Comment: Oh huh, it doesn't work after all. Interesting. I was under the impression that jQuery's event delegation worked similarly to `.matches` in native Javascript, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/u8z1wtg2/ But jQuery's behavior is different for some reason. It must only filter *descendants*, but not the base element the listener is added to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I got your point,Thanks again :))

Answer (score 3):

Use `e.stopPropagation();` method on your child elements.

```js
jQuery('#anything').on("click", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

        });
jQuery('#a1').on("click", function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="anything">
    <a href="https://google.com" id="a1"> Link should work </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your solution Works too, Great, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

To stop preventDefault() to pass to **all** child element, you have to use `stopPropagation` on all children's clicked

```js
jQuery('#anything').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 }).children().click(function(e) { // catch all children click
    e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="anything">
    <a href="https://google.com"> Link should work </a>
 </div>
```