# jquery dropdown menu links not clickable

Tags: jquery

jquery dropdown menu links not clickable

I have the following code when click any link on dropdown menu not working any link why

please check the example below
and try to click google or facebook links

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.dropdown_parent', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var getId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    if (
      $('#drop_' + getId).is(":visible")) {
      $('#drop_' + getId).hide();
    } else {
      $('.dropdown_child').hide();
      $('#drop_' + getId).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown_parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown_child {
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #FFF;
  min-width: 100%;
  color: #373737;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown_parent" data-id="111">
  <div id="down_parent">drop menu ...</div>
  <div style="left: 0px; width: 120px; display: none;" id="drop_111" class="dropdown_child text-start">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a><br>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com">facebook</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you think `e.preventDefault()` does?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript, Stop preventDefault() to pass to child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588890/javascript-stop-preventdefault-to-pass-to-child-element)

Comment: @Phil , thanks Phil , seems stupid question from me,

Comment: No, not stupid at all. Event bubbling / propagation isn't always obvious. Sorry if my first comment came across as derogatory